# Where is codesign information stored for files that are not in a bundle?

Tags: macos, codesign

I noticed that I am able to digitally sign any random file:

```
touch ~/test
md5 ~/test
  -> MD5 (~/test) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
codesign -vv ~/test
  ->  code object is not signed at all
codesign -s <Developer ID Certificate Hash> ~/test
md5 ~/test
  -> MD5 (~/test) = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
codesign -vv ~/test
  -> valid on disk
  -> satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

If it was a bundle, the codesign info would be stored here:
MyBundle.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/

But in this case, there is no bundle, and the checksum of the file is not changes, so where does the code signature get stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a great question!

If you touch the file and look at it with `ls` you'll see something like this:

```
$ ls -la test
-rw-r--r--    1 User  staff  0 17 Oct 09:42 test
```

Codesign the file and list it again

```
$ ls -la test
-rw-r--r--@   1 User  staff  0 17 Oct 09:42 test
```

You'll see that the 2nd listing has a `@` at the end of the permissions, which tells us that there's one or more extended attributes.

We can view the data there with a call to `xattr`

```
$ xattr -l test
```

And that will display the code signature data, which is stored as an extended attribute of the file.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense.